# Apache Spark application framework

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We're developing lots of small Spark applications in PySpark. The issue is that all the programs need very similar settings and often need to do common things like creating directories and things like that. Often applications are simply doing a query and writing it to a CSV file. I wonder if anyone knows of a good way to manage these kind of scripts to focus each application on the logic and not on the boilerplate.

In web development people invented Spring to facilitate common tasks and have sensible defaults. In Spark world we're back to using shell scripts to run the Spark applications. Is there a best practice in packaging pyspark apps? The Spark documentation only explain the mechanisms, not the day to day usage of writing Spark apps.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark using Java,Scala and Python not diffrent then normal programming , you can reuse your code using design pattern.

Comment: it's not the code itself, it's all the plumbing around it